# Get txt file size

Tags: vbscript

I am using standalone .vbs file to verify files whether each file exists or not.I also wants to check Wether the file size is exact? 
Is it possible to do it with vbscript? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the code that you have tried until now ?

Comment: @Hackoo Absolutely the right response unfortunately this behaviour is always going to be encouraged when there are those that answer regardless of question quality!

Comment: Of course you *could* simply have close-voted ...

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have, just don't understand why those who should know better don't leave these types of questions alone. Plus so could Ekkehard, so what's your point? If anything you two are the biggest offenders when it comes to this type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [.Size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d66skaf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property of the File object:

```
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetFile("c:\boot.ini").Size
>>
211
>>
```